# Loop outputting blank variables - SSH Bash

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, ssh

I am writing a script to help me sync files between my home pc and my server. One of the problems ive run into is that, when I run the for loop, it outputs blank lines.

Everything else seems to be fine, `echo $REMOTE` lists all files and their full paths as expected. I have tried unquoting, quoting, Changing EOF from "EOF" to EOF etc, but so far nothing has worked.

Here is the script below:

```
function uploadDownload()
{
    if [ "$1" == "d" ]; then
        ssh -i ~/Dropbox/Business/aws/first.pem ubuntu@XXXX.194.202 << EOF
        echo $REMOTE

        for file in $REMOTE; do
            echo $file
        done
EOF
        #scp -r -i ~/Dropbox/Business/aws/first.pem ubuntu@XXXX.194.202:$REMOTE $LOCAL
    elif [ "$1" == "u" ]; then
        scp -r -i ~/Dropbox/Business/aws/first.pem $LOCAL ubuntu@XXXX.194.202:$REMOTE
    fi
}


if [ "$2" == "m" ]; then

    if [ -z "$3" ]; then
        echo "Please enter the local location of the files and provide an absolute path..."
        read LOCAL
        echo "Please enter the remote location of the files..."
        read REMOTE
        uploadDownload
    else
        LOCAL=$2
        if [ -z "$4" ]; then
            REMOTE=$3
        else
            REMOTE='ubuntu@XXXX.194.202:~/test/'
        fi  
        uploadDownload
    fi
else
    LOCAL='/home/will/Dropbox/Business/aws/files/binaryhustle/'
    REMOTE='/home/ubuntu/dev/binaryhustle/*'
    uploadDownload $1
fi
```

EDIT: based on advice I have edited the uploadDownload function. I should also note than I tested `echo "$REMOTE";` outside of the loop and it returns nothing (unlike without quotes, where it returns something).

```
function uploadDownload()
    {
        if [ "$1" == "d" ]; then
            ssh -i ~/Dropbox/Business/aws/first.pem ubuntu@54.252.194.202 << EOF
    for file in "/home/ubuntu/dev/binaryhustle"; do
    echo $file
    done
    EOF
            #scp -r -i ~/Dropbox/Business/aws/first.pem ubuntu@54.252.194.202:$REMOTE $LOCAL
        elif [ "$1" == "u" ]; then
            scp -r -i ~/Dropbox/Business/aws/first.pem $LOCAL ubuntu@54.252.194.202:$REMOTE
        fi
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to quote your variable `$file` as it is expanded before being sent to the remote server:

```
            echo $file
```

To

```
            echo \$file
```

Or better yet

```
            echo \"\$file\"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/). Its powerful file syncing tool able to work over ssh. It doesn't do any content diff though.

Comment: Thanks I actually ended up using rsync. I will post the final code for others.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @konsolebox for getting me half way there, I got it working by adding the slash to file, however this did not work with << EOF , only <

```
function uploadDownload()
{
    if [ "$1" == "d" ]; then
            ssh -i ~/Dropbox/Business/aws/first.pem ubuntu@54.252.194.202 <<EOF
for file in "$REMOTE"; do
echo \$file
done
EOF
            #scp -r -i ~/Dropbox/Business/aws/first.pem ubuntu@54.252.194.202:$REMOTE $LOCAL
        elif [ "$1" == "u" ]; then
            scp -r -i ~/Dropbox/Business/aws/first.pem $LOCAL ubuntu@54.252.194.202:$REMOTE
        fi
    }
```

Comment: Did you try not to indent your delimiter `EOF`?. Also since you quoted $REMOTE this time (`"$REMOTE"`), it would just expand to one word. I may have suggested quoting your variables before but not for one you really intend to be processed with word splitting. (Edit: Arrays won't be applicable to that. One added note deleted.)

Comment: And please tell us why it still doesn't work, and what mod actually worked. I read it as you used `<EOF` instead?

Comment: Yes the delimiter is not indented, removing the space between << and EOF is what fixed it (in addition to adding the slash) `<<EOF` instead of `<< EOF`.